# Есть Проблема с кодом, который по идее должен копировать 2-D массив в такой же массив внутри объекта

Tags: c++, массивы, windows, ооп, указатели

При копировании, правильно передаётся только 1 строка, дальше идёт какой то мусор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемная Функция

```
 template<class element>
    void plane_metric::frame<element>::copy_paste(const int left_up_string, const int left_up_collumn, const int other_start_string, const int other_start_collumn, const int other_end_string, const int other_end_collumn, element** buffer, const int size_ex, const element* exception, const element* replace)
    {
        if (overflow(left_up_string, left_up_collumn, other_end_string, other_end_collumn) && overflow(other_start_string, other_start_collumn, other_end_string, other_end_collumn)) {
            int other_str = other_start_string;
            int other_coll = other_start_collumn;
            int copy_str = other_end_string - other_start_string;
            int copy_coll = other_end_string - other_start_string;
            element** copy_buffer = new element * [copy_str];
            for (size_t init = 0; init < copy_str; init++) {
                copy_buffer[init] = new element[copy_coll];
            }
            if (size_ex == 0) {
                for (size_t str = 0; str < copy_str; str++) {
                    for (size_t coll = 0; coll < copy_coll; coll++) {
                        copy_buffer[str][coll] = buffer[other_str][other_coll];
                        other_coll++;
                    }
                    other_str++;
                    other_coll = other_start_collumn;
                }
            }
            else {
                bool skip = false;
                for (size_t str = 0; str < copy_str; str++) {
                    for (size_t coll = 0; coll < copy_coll; coll++) {
                        for (size_t ex = 0; ex < size_ex; ex++) {
                            if (buffer[str][coll] == exception[ex]) {
                                copy_buffer[str][coll] = replace[ex];
                                skip = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (skip) {
                            skip = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                        copy_buffer[str][coll] = buffer[other_str][other_coll];
                        other_coll++;
                    }
                    other_str++;
                }
            }
            other_str   = 0;
            other_coll  = 0;
            for (size_t str = left_up_string; str < copy_str; str++) {
                for (size_t coll = left_up_collumn; coll < copy_coll; coll++) {
                    this->plane[str][coll] = copy_buffer[other_str][other_coll];
                    other_coll++;
                }
                other_str++;
            }
            for (size_t del = 0; del < copy_str; del++) {
                delete[] copy_buffer[del];
            }
            delete[] copy_buffer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, нужно добавить `other_coll = other_start_collumn;` в предпоследний цикл.

Comment: проблема решена, значит нужно удалять вопрос

Comment: С одной стороны вопрос может быть полезным если он реально был актуален и на его решение было потрачено приличное количество времени. Но с другой - ответ дан через 2 минуты после публикации вопроса. Ответ как буд-то был готов до публикации вопроса.  Синтетические ошибки хороши для исследования , но в практической жизни - бесполезны ввиду динамичного  изменения сред разрабботки и модификаций самих языков програмирования.

Comment: @V.March, вы правы, вопросы с собственным ответом могут быть полезны, но  точно не такой вопрос. Тут не важно потраченное время на ответ, а важна именно полезность,  которой, лично я, тут не вижу.